# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_M_construct null not valid, class string variable

Tags: c++, string, binary-search-tree

Code as Follows:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Monster{
public:
    int health;
    int speed;
    int damage;
    string name;

    Monster(int inHealth, int inSpeed,int inDamage, string inName){
        health = inHealth;
        speed = inSpeed;
        damage = inDamage;
        name = inName;
        cout<< name<< " created"<<endl;
    }

    int Attack(Monster * opponent){
        opponent->health = opponent->health - this->damage;
        cout<< this->name << " attacked " << opponent->name << " for "<< this->damage <<"     damage!"<<endl;
        cout<<"New " << opponent->name <<" health is: "<< opponent->health<<endl;
    }

    string getName(){
        //if (name != string()){
             return name;
       // }
       // else{
        //    return("error: name is null");
      //  }
    }
};

class Node{
public:
    Monster* mob;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

class BST{
public:
    Node* root;

    BST(){
        root = NULL;
    }

    void add(int inHealth, int inSpeed,int inDamage, string inName){
        Node* n = new Node();
        Monster holder = Monster(inHealth, inSpeed, inDamage, inName);
        n->mob = &holder;
        if (root == NULL) {
            root = n;
            cout<<"was null"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            Node * iter = root;
            while(1){
                if(inSpeed > inDamage){
                    if(iter->left==NULL){
                        iter->left=n;
                        return ;
                    }
                    else{
                        iter = iter->left;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(iter->right==NULL){
                        iter->right=n;
                        return ;
                    }
                    else{
                        iter = iter->right;
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    inFile.open("Mobs.txt");
    outFile.open("Score.txt");

    BST dungeon = BST();

    string nameHolder;
    string healthHolder;
    string damageHolder;
    string speedHolder;
    int healthHold;
    int damageHold;
    int speedHold;

    int weapon = 3;
    int pSpeed;
    int pDamage;
    if(weapon = 1){ //Knife
        pSpeed = 75;
        pDamage = 15;
    }
    else if(weapon = 2){ //Axe
        pSpeed = 1;
        pDamage = 60;
    }
    else{ //Sword
        pSpeed = 50;
        pDamage = 50;
    }

    Monster player = Monster(100, pDamage, pSpeed, "Player");

    while(getline(inFile, nameHolder, ',')) {
        getline(inFile, healthHolder, ',');
        getline(inFile, speedHolder, ',');
        getline(inFile, damageHolder);
        healthHold = stoi(healthHolder);
        damageHold = stoi(damageHolder);
        speedHold = stoi(speedHolder);
        dungeon.add(healthHold, speedHold,damageHold, nameHolder);
    }

    Monster *testMon = new Monster(100, 10, 10, "TestMob");
    Monster *currentMonster = dungeon.root->mob;

    cout<<"here1"<<endl;
    cout<< dungeon.root->mob->name<<endl;
    cout<< testMon->getName()<<endl;
    cout<< currentMonster->getName() <<endl;
    cout<<"here2"<<endl;
    while(player.health >0){
        cout<<"here"<<endl;
        if(player.speed > currentMonster->speed){
            player.Attack(currentMonster);
        }
        else(currentMonster->Attack(&player));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Console output is:

```
Player created
Green Slime created
was null
Blue Slime created
Blue Slime created
Red Slime created
Red Slime created
Fire Golem created
Ice Golem created
Water Golem created
Fire Elemental created
Ice Elemental created
Water Elemental created
TestMob created
here1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid

Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 0.364 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Not sure what is causing this error, seems like it involves the `Monster` name string not being properly created, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 2):

```
void add(int inHealth, int inSpeed,int inDamage, string inName){

// ...

    Monster holder = Monster(inHealth, inSpeed, inDamage, inName);
```

This `holder` object gets declared as an object in `add()` with automatic scope. That's what this declaration means, and when `add()` returns `holder` gets destroyed automatically.

```
  n->mob = &holder;
```

A pointer to this object get stored in this `Node`.

Later code attempts to access the object referenced by this pointer, but after `add()` already returned. Once `add()` returns the pointer is pointing to a destroyed object, and all subsequent attempts to access it results in undefined behavior, and the likely reason for your crash.

This entire binary tree ends up with pointers to destroyed objects.